# Adding a photo to a model's has_many model from a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model, Thing, that has a has_many with ThingPhoto, using Paperclip to manage everything. On the "show" view for Thing, I want to have a file upload, and have it relate to the Thing model.

For some reason, I'm totally glitching on how this should be done. I've tried doing this (Haml):

```
- form_for @thing.thing_photos, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
  = f.file_field :photo
  = f.submit
```

... and I get this error:

```
undefined method `array_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x24d42b4>
```

Google is failing me. I'm sure this is super easy, but I just can't get my brain around it.

Edit: I should have mentioned that if I change the @thing.thing_photos to just @thing, it works fine, in that it displays the form, but of course it's not associated with the correct model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `@thing.thing_photos.new`

this should instance a new model of thing_photos. If you're not using nested routes you'll have to add the thing_id as a hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not tied to Paperclip (and if you're just doing images), I've had a *lot* of luck with [fleximage](http://github.com/Squeegy/fleximage/tree/master). It's got really good documentation for image upload, manipulation, and display (with all sorts of neat effects like watermarking and stuff).

It doesn't quite answer your question, but it might be a cool thing to look into.

But I bet your problem related to the fact you're creating a form for an array of objects (through an association). I bet something is finding the type of the object (should be "thing_photo" but is "array" in your example), and appending "path" to it to write the form post URL. Perhaps you should add a `.first` or create a partial?

Answer (score 0):

The form should be for @thing_photo and should either pass in the thing_id or if it's a nested route you can get it from that

then in your thing_photos controller

```
@thing_photo = Photo.new(params[:thing_photo])
#if using nested route
@thing = Thing.find(params[:thing_id])

#if using hidden field
@thing = Thing.find(params[:thing_photo][:thing_id])

if @thing_photo.save
  #this is what ties the thing photo to the thing
  @thing.thing_photos << @thing_photo
end
```

If I understand the question correctly, this might help.